# Passing an object as props and receiving it

Tags: reactjs

I have a component `Data` and its child component `BarChart`.

`Data` component looks as following:

```
export default class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
          label: "",
          data: [],
          backgroundColor: ''
        }]
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.geData();
  }

  geData = () => {
    let labelsData = someContent;
    let datasets = otherContentl;
    this.setState({data: {...this.state.data, labels: labelsData, datasets: datasets}}, ()=>{console.log(this.state.data)});
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <BarChart data={this.state.data} />
    );
  }
}
```

When I check the result of `console.log(this.state.data)` in `getData` function, it prints out the correct data.
However, when I receive the props in `BarChart` component, I only receive  `datasets` key filled with the correct data, but `labels` key is an empty array.

```
export default class BarChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {    
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }

componentWillMount() { 
    this.setState({chartData: this.props.data});
}

render() {
        return (
            <div className="barChart">
                <Bar
                    data={this.state.chartData}
                />
            </div>
        );
}
}
```

Why does that happen? How can it be fixed?

Comment: You call `getData` in `componentDidMount` which is run after the initial render, so your `BarChart` will already have been rendered and had its constructor run.

Comment: Logging props in constructor won't show you the updated props. Do console.log(props) in render method and you will see the correct response

Comment: @Shubham Khatri I logged `props ` in `render` mothod.
But it printed out the result twice; first time with an empty ` labels` array, second time with the correct data.

How can I fix it?

Comment: that is the expected behaviour unless you prevent render of BarChart till the data is available after the getdata call

Comment: @Shubham Khatri Thanks a lot. How can I prevent render of BarChart till the data is available after the getData call?

Comment: set a state isLoading to true, and once you get the response in getdata call, set isLoading state to false and in render method, render BarChart if isLoading is false else return null or a Loading Spinner

Comment: @Shubham Khatri Thank you so much. It's so useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had in `BarChart` component is:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        chartData: {}
    }
}

componentWillMount() { 
    this.setState({chartData: this.props.data});
}

render() {
        return (
            <div className="barChart">
                <Bar
                    data={this.state.chartData}
                />
            </div>
        );
}
```

What I changed is receiving the props immediately and using it, instead of receiving it in state or componentWillMount:

```
export default class BarChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentWillMount() { }

    componentDidMount() { }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="barChart">
                <Bar
                    data={this.props.data}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So, whenever the props is changed, the component will re-render.